# Put oversize image in parent container

Tags: html, css

I need to put the image in the parent container. The image is larger than the parent's size, need to scale the height of the parent and hide everything oversized. The width of the parent is not explicitly defined, there is only the height calculated using Calc. Don't want to use background:url, because image will use area map

```
.container
{
height: calc(100vh - 56px);
overflow: hidden;
}

.container img
{
height: auto;
max-height: 100%
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
<img src="/img/spec3/panel.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: What's the problem that you're having with the above code? Looks fine to me.

Comment: No, image broke parents width

Comment: There is nothing in your code to suggest there is a necessary width for the container. You may want to update question with full code to show more of the scenario you're trying to fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

better option to give it object-fit: cover as well

```css
.container
{
height: calc(100vh - 56px);
overflow: hidden;
border: 5px solid red;
position: relative;
}

.container img
{
display: block; 
position: absolute; 
top: 50%; 
left: 50%;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
object-fit: cover;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/uw-s3-cdn/wp-content/uploads/sites/6/2017/11/04133712/waterfall.jpg" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution

```
.container 
{ 
height: calc(100vh - 56px); 
overflow: hidden; 
position: relative; 
margin: 0; 
} 

.container img 
{ 
display: block; 
position: absolute; 
top: 50%; 
left: 50%;
max-height: 100%; 
transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
}
```

Comment: in this solution, you will get your image stretched.

Comment: No, why? Image keep own size perfectly

Comment: Your questions says "need to scale it to the height of the parent and hide everything oversized" - your code does not scale the height of the image to be the same size as the parent container.